# 3-columned bibliography

Tags: biblatex, columns

I have some difficulties with the layout of my bibliography. It should have three columns like this:

- Column 1: [number]
- Column 2: author(s)
- Column 3: title, year, …

I’m not happy with my recent solution, because the numbers in column 1 aren’t aligned to the top.

here's the code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{mwe2012,
  author  = {Smith, A. and Johnson, B. and Willians, C.},
  title   = {The three most common surnames in the United States of America},
  journal = {Review of Useless Knowledge},
  year    = {2012},
  volume  = {8},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {290--290},
}
@BOOK{mwe2012asdf,
  author  = {Smith, A. and Johnson, B. and Willians, C.},
  title   = {The three most common surnames in the United States of America},
  journal = {Review of Useless Knowledge},
  year    = {2012},
  volume  = {8},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {290--290},
}
@ARTICLE{mwe2011,
  author  = {Miller, J. and Brown, D.},
  title   = {Most used surnames in fake passports},
  journal = {Journal of Nosense Ranks},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1--130},
  pmid    = {1234567},
  url     = {http://www.mwe.com/mwe2011},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/jnr.2011.01.01},
}
@ARTICLE{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@ARTICLE{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}


@ARTICLE{mwe20122,
  author  = {Smith, A. and Johnson, B. and Willians, C.},
  title   = {The three most common surnames in the United States of America},
  journal = {Review of Useless Knowledge},
  year    = {2012},
  volume  = {8},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {290--290},
}
@ARTICLE{mwe20112,
  author  = {Miller, J. and Brown, D.},
  title   = {Most used surnames in fake passports},
  journal = {Journal of Nosense Ranks},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1--130},
  pmid    = {1234567},
  url     = {http://www.mwe.com/mwe2011},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/jnr.2011.01.01},
}
@ARTICLE{einstein2,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@ARTICLE{Goossens2,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}



@ARTICLE{mwe20123,
  author  = {Smith, A. and Johnson, B. and Willians, C.},
  title   = {The three most common surnames in the United States of America},
  journal = {Review of Useless Knowledge},
  year    = {2012},
  volume  = {8},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {290--290},
}
@ARTICLE{mwe20113,
  author  = {Miller, J. and Brown, D.},
  title   = {Most used surnames in fake passports},
  journal = {Journal of Nosense Ranks},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1--130},
  pmid    = {1234567},
  url     = {http://www.mwe.com/mwe2011},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/jnr.2011.01.01},
}
@ARTICLE{einstein3,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@ARTICLE{Goossens3,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}



\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}


% ------------- Schrift --------------
% ------------------------------------------
\usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %% Schriftkodierung, die nativ Umlaute unterstützt 
\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref} % Querverweise mit Seitenreferenz
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref} % es wird automatisch "Abschnitt/Abbildung/Tabelle/Kapitel" 2.3.1 geschrieben
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss} % schönere Schrift
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}


%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{array}    % > in table
\usepackage{ragged2e} % \RaggedRight in table

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[%
  backend      = biber, 
  maxnames     = 99, 
%  sorting      = nyvt, 
sorting=none, %  Mit der Einstellung sorting=none wird nicht sortiert, sondern die Einträge werden in der Reihenfolge, in der sie zitiert werden aufgeführt. 
  hyperref     = true, 
  maxcitenames = 2,
  mincitenames = 1,
  natbib       = true,
  giveninits   = true, % firstinits
  style        = numeric, 
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}


%%\newrobustcmd{\mkbibslashes}[1]{/#1/}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{mkbibslashes}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}                  % no punct after entry

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibslashes]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}



%\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
%  {\list
%     {\ifentrytype{article}
%       {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{
%         \printtext[labelalphawidth]{% mkbibslashes
%           \printfield{prefixnumber}%
%           \printfield{labelalpha}%
%           \printfield{extraalpha}}%
%            %\addspace%
%            %\MakeSentenceCase{\thefield{entrytype}}%
%       }}
%       {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{% mkbibslashes
%          \printfield{prefixnumber}%
%          \printfield{labelalpha}%
%          \printfield{extraalpha}}}}
%     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%\labelnumberwidth or \labelalphawidth
%      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
%      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
%      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
%      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
%      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
%      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}% \hss##1
%  {\endlist}
%  {\item}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}



%% \DeclareNameFormat[article]{author}{\dotfill #1 \dotfill}
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\bf #1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\enquote{#1}}%\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\emph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{S.~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1}



\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
\begin{tabular}[]{>{\RaggedRight}p{0.3\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.02\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.68\textwidth}}\\ 
  \printnames{author} &  
  &  % um Abstand zu erh�hen
    \printfield{title}\newunit \printfield{year}\newunit  
    \printfield{journaltitle}\newunit \printfield{volume}\newunit
    \printfield{number}\newunit \printfield{pages}\newunit 
    \printfield{url}\newunit \printfield{doi}\newunit \\%
\end{tabular}
%\vspace{1em}% 1em
%\hrule
\usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
\begin{tabular}[]{>{\RaggedRight}p{0.3\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.02\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.68\textwidth}}\\ 
  \printnames{author} &  
  &  % um Abstand zu erh�hen
    \printfield{title}\newunit \printfield{year}\newunit  
    \printfield{journaltitle}\newunit \printfield{volume}\newunit
    \printfield{number}\newunit \printfield{pages}\newunit 
    \printfield{url}\newunit \printfield{doi}\newunit \\%
\end{tabular}
%\vspace{1em}% 1em
%\hrule
\usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}

%\nocite{*} 
asdfafwer\autocite[]{einstein}\autocite[]{mwe2011}\\
asdfafwer\autocite[]{einstein2}\autocite[]{mwe20112}\\
asdfafwer\autocite[]{einstein3}\autocite[]{mwe20113}\\
asdfafwer\autocite[]{einstein3}\autocite[]{mwe2012asdf}



\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\RaggedRight}p{0.3\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.02\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.68\textwidth}}
  \printnames{author} &  
  &  % um Abstand zu erhöhen
...
```

By the way, I think to get extra spacing it is nicer to use `@{\hspace{...}` instead of a dummy column `>{\RaggedRight}p{0.02\textwidth}`. And then leave out the extra `&  % um Abstand zu erhöhen`. For a column that contains no text `>{\RaggedRight}` doesn't make sense anyway.